# Is sleep() blocking the handling of requests in Django?

Tags: python, django

In Django, if the view uses a sleep() function while answering a request, does this block the handling of the whole queue of requests?

If so, how to delay an http answer without this blocking behavior? Can we do that out-of-the-box and avoid using a job queue like Celeri?

Comment: It depends on your web server. If it is behind Apache, then yes - out of the box. If it is Nginx, then not necessarly.

Comment: You should never `sleep()` in the main thread. If you need to wait for something, then fire off a new thread and handle the code execution there. Even if you don't end up blocking the entire server, you're blocking workers, and eventually you will run out of workers.

Answer (score 1):

I would image that calling `sleep()` should block the execution of all Django code in most cases. However it might depend on the deployment architecture (e.g. gevent, gunicorn, etc). For instance if you are using a server which fires Django threads for each request, then no it will not block all the code.

In most cases however using something like Celeri would like to be a much better solution because (1) don't reinvent the wheel and (2) it has been tested.